# Dart: how to dynamically set document's body's innerHTML

Tags: dart, dart-html

I see that Dart has a [`BodyElement`](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/be/latest/dart_html/BodyElement.html) class, and that it has an `innerHTML` property.

I also see that you can access the current document's body via `window.document.body`, however, there are no getter/setter methods for this `body` property.

So I'm trying to link the two together: how I dyamically set the current document's body's inner HTML? I'm looking for something like:

```dart
String html = "<p><h1>I'm dynamic</h1>";
window.document.body = bodyElementFactory.newBodyElement(html);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options:

```dart
querySelector('body').appendHtml("<p><h1>I'm dynamic</h1>");
```

or

```dart
querySelector('body').innerHtml = "<p><h1>I'm dynamic</h1>";
```

Answer (score 3):

this should work for dart 1.14+

```
String html = "<p><h1>I'm dynamic</h1>";
querySelector('body').setInnerHtml(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.body` returns `BodyElement`. You could do the following if you wanted:

```dart
document.body.innerHtml = "<h1>I'm dynamic</h1>";
```